# How do I stop the screen from rotating?

Tags: display

Sometimes I'm just sitting there and my laptop screen rotates, or when I get up and pick my laptop up from working on my couch and move to the kitchen table, it's now upside down.  I can fix it by turning the laptop on angle to rotate it as I need it, but how do I shut this off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [screen flip issue with Juno 5.0 on HP 840 G1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/screen-flip-issue-with-juno-5-0-on-hp-840-g1)

Comment: i have that problem wit my seti sscreensaver keeps rotating iys a Toshiba satilite

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps,

1. At first, go to `System Settings` and click `Displays`.
2. After that, click on the `gear` icon on the top-right side and select `None` from the drop down menu of `Screen Rotation`.
3. At the end, hit `Apply` and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `System Settings` and select the `Displays` option.
From there, you may notice a switch at the bottom of the window to toggle rotation lock. This should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just press the `"Super" key + "o"`, to toggle screen rotation
(It's "o" as in "oreo" and not zero).

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: why is this not the top answer?